# Win32 force windowed mode on process

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm looking to force an application to be windowed (like you would with alt+enter) even if it starts in full screen mode.

My initial thought was to use user32.dll "ShowWindow" with either "Restore" or "ShowNormal". However if it started full screen it will not work.

Is there any way to force any given application to be windowed using c#?

Comment: Full screen mode isn't an inherent window state like maximized or minimized, it's something that an application implements itself.

Comment: Since you are talking about *"any given application"*, are you really referring to *full screen mode*, or a *maximized window*?

Comment: Are you sure? Full screen seems to have consistent behaviour throughout windows and is controlable by default shortcuts such as alt+enter. Surely this is rooted in the win api?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to send messages to the app's window to get it behave.  I remember there is this app for a MMORPG game and it was called "Windower"  It forced the game, Final Fantasy 11, to run in a window.  It was used until the vendor made their own windowing code back in 2007 or 2008.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This is the moral equivalent of a link-only answer. Except, without a link.